# DBContext, access navigational property of newly Added entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to access Navigational property of entity having State = Added, but the Navigational property is null.

```
    using (var myc = new DBTestEntities())
    {
        var cust = new Customer();
        cust.CustomerName = "New Customer";
        cust.BusinessTypeID = 1;  // This is a valid BusinessTypeID present in BusinessType table

        myc.Customers.Add(cust);
        // at this point cust.BusinessType is null
        Console.WriteLine(cust.BusinessType.BusinessTypeName);
    }
```

Can anyone guide my how to access Navigational property in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the line

```
myc.Customers.Add(cust);
```

you can add

```
myc.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
```

This will trigger a process called relationship fixup, in which EF synchronizes all properties involved in foreign keys. It will cause the `BusinessType` object to be fetched from the database if it is not in the context yet.

Comment: That does the trick. I think the correct approach is to set the BusinessType NOT the BusinessTypeID (as TheJoelaut mentioned), and use BusinessType navigational property everywhere. But in my case I will be using BusinessTypeID field and then I need to check the BusinessType. However it would be better to have some sort of option that navigational property should populate itself on read.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a BusinessType Property in your Customer Class.

There you can set the Businesstype something like :

```
cust.BusinessType = (from x in myc.BusinessTypes where x.Id=1 Select x).First();
```

Comment: OK but then whats the point of whole database context, ORM, relational navigation, etc.? Am I missing something?

Comment: BTW BusinessType property is already there as a Navigational property

Comment: The Navigation Property is the Busniesstype Property. The BusinessTypeId is only the foreign key.

Comment: Yes that is what I am saying. Customer is an Entity, having BusinessTypeID an integer property and BusinessType property as object of BusinessType Entity, which is a navigational property

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do:

```
myc.SaveChanges();
```

to actually submit the enitity to the database.

Comment: But I don't want to save changes just yet.